# Asignar innerHTML a un elemento de un querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una serie de divs con clases distintas, pero dentro de cada uno de estos divs, existen otros divs. Lo que intento es:

1. Seleccionar al padre.
2. Luego seleccionar a uno de sus hijos (El que contenga una clase específica).
3. A este hijo, mediante **innerHTML += "texto"** asignarle un pedazo de HTML.

El 1 y 2 lo conseguí así...

```
let areaElement = document.querySelectorAll(".alumno_"+alumno_id+" > .be-area-rating");
```

Con un query selector selecciono al padre... E inmediatamente le digo cual de los hijos debe seleccionar.

Pero cuando a esto intento ponerle un **innerHTML** me sale `undefined`.

```
let areaElement = document.querySelectorAll(".alumno_"+alumno.alumno_id+" > .be-area-rating").innerHTML;
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

El HTML es este; estoy usando Laravel por eso uso `{{}}` para declarar una variable:

```
<div class="cell not-border alumno_{{$alumno->alumno_id}}" id="be-area-rating">
<div class="rowTable be-area-rating">
    <div class="cell rating do-area">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating do-area">20</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cell not-border alumno_{{$alumno->alumno_id}} " id="do-area-rating">
<div class="rowTable do-area-rating">
    <div class="cell rating do-area">20</div>
    <div class="cell rating do-area">20</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo del HTML ??

Comment: claro, dame un minuto

Comment: Ya no importa :P Te acaban de dar la respuesta

Comment: En todo caso "be-area-rating" la tienes como clase única, podría usarla y listo documen.querySelector(".be-area-rating")

Comment: be-area-rating es unica dentro de cada **div alumno** pero, existen muchos **div alumno* solo que cada uno tiene un distinto numero de alumno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tengo una solucion parecida fijate si te da una idea de lo que queres:

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".containers").forEach(container => { // para cada contenedor:
        for(const children of container.children){ // para cada hijo del contenedor: 
          if(children.classList.contains("claseespecial")) children.innerHTML = `<p>AQUI SE INSERTO UN PARRAFO EN LA CLASE ESPECIAL</p>` 
          // si contiene la clase especificada se agrega un <p> con un msj
     }
})
```

como tenes elementos dentro de otros elementos tenes que hacer una doble iteracion para comprobar si tiene la clase especificada o no.

Comment: Esta solucion si funcionaria. De todas maneras, encontre una solucion en menos lineas de codigo... simplemente debia poner **.[0].innerHTML** ya que se trataba de un array. Y ya con eso quedó. Pero muchas gracias, tu solucion es valida

Comment: @AldahirRuizValdez si ocupas [0] es que no necesitas el array, pone sencillamente document.querySelector(".alumno_"+alumno.alumno_id+" > .be-area-rating")

Comment: @Yussef justamente eso pensaba, si va directamente por el indice es porque ya sabe cual elemento tiene la clase especifica, yo supuse que tenia que hacer una busqueda entre todos los hijos y verificar esa condicion.

Comment: Por algun motivo, si no pongo el [0] no me permite poner el innerHTML, mea rroja undefined... pero con el [0] funciona bien, no entiendo porque. Yo pense lo mismo, se supone que estoy seleccionando ya a uno de sus hijos especifico, (osea la clase be-area-rating) pero por algun motivo no me deja si no pongo la posicion del array

Answer (score 3):

QuerySelectorAll devuelve un array, no tiene innerHTML
debes trabajarlo con un iterador

Comment: Gracias, la respuesta me ayudó. Pero en mi caso, como ya seleccinaba un elemento especifico, lo que me faltaba era determinar en el array la posicion. En mi cas element.[0].innerHTML